# How do I make this program continue? It just stops

Tags: python

```
import random
import time


print("Welcome to the Dojo!")
print("You have three opponents; they are ready...")
print("Are you?")
print("*To view the rules, type 'rules' ")
print("*To view commands, type 'commands' ")
print("*To begin, type 'start' ")

while True:
    userInput = input()
    # Rules
    if userInput == "rules":
        print("The rules in this Dojo are simple. Kill your opponent! Fight to the death! Show no mercy!")
        print("Each opponent gets progressively more difficult, whether it be in terms of health or damage.")
        print("To attack, type 'attack'")
        print("May the better (luckier) warrior win")
    # Commands - to be added

        # print("Commands will be added soon!")



    # Start
    elif userInput == "start":


        '''
        print("Your first opponent is Larry Schmidt. Don't sweat it, he'll be a piece of cake.")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("The battle will begin in")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("5")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("4")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("3")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("2")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("1")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Fight!")
        '''

        userHealth = 100
        opponentHealth = 100
        while opponentHealth > 0 or userHealth > 0:

            userInput = input()

            if userInput == "attack":
                userDamage = random.randint(0, 100)
                opponentDamage = random.randint(0, 20)
                opponentOne = "Larry"
                opponentHealth -= userDamage

                if opponentHealth <= 0:
                    opponentHealth = 0

                if (userDamage < 25) and (userDamage > 0):
                    quoteOptions = [("You roundhouse kick {} in the abdomen and he begins to vomit.".format(
                        opponentOne)), ("You punch {} in the stomach and he begins to tear up.".format(opponentOne))]

                    print(random.choice(quoteOptions))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("You did {} damage to him".format(userDamage))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("He has {} health remaining.".format(opponentHealth))
                    print("---------------------------------------------------")


                elif (userDamage < 100) and (userDamage > 25):
                    quoteOptions = [("You drive your foot into {}'s groin with as much force as possible. You hear a high-pitched scream emit from his vocal chords.".format(
                            opponentOne)), ("{} is intimidated by you and decides to slap himself mindlessly, in hopes that he will lose faster.".format(
                            opponentOne))]
                    print(random.choice(quoteOptions))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("You did {} damage to him; a CRITICAL HIT!".format(userDamage))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("He has {} health remaining.".format(opponentHealth))
                    print("---------------------------------------------------")


                elif userDamage == 100:
                    print("{} forfeits... Coward.".format(opponentOne))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("You did {} damage to him. INSTANT K.O".format(userDamage))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("He has {} health remaining.".format(opponentHealth))
                    print("---------------------------------------------------")

                else:
                    quoteOptions = [("Swing and a miss. You missed {}.".format(opponentOne)), ("You underestimated {}".format(
                        opponentOne))]
                    print(random.choice(quoteOptions))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("You did {} damage to him.".format(userDamage))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("He has {} health remaining.".format(opponentHealth))
                    print("---------------------------------------------------")


                # Opponent Attack
                if opponentHealth - 1 < opponentHealth:
                    userHealth = userHealth - opponentDamage
                    time.sleep(2)
                    print("Larry gathers the courage to punch you. Meh." or "Larry throws his shoe at you and starts to yell frantically while running away from you... You catch up soon enough, without breaking much of a sweat.")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("He did {} damage to you." .format(opponentDamage))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("You have {} health remaining." .format(userHealth))
                    print("---------------------------------------------------")

                if userHealth <= 0:
                        print("You lose!")
                        print("Come back do the Dojo when you become stronger. You are welcome back anytime, grasshopper.")
                        quit()

                elif opponentHealth <= 0:
                        print("You win!")
                        break




        #Next Opponent

        userHealth = 100
        opponentHealth = 100
        while opponentHealth > 0 or userHealth > 0:
            if opponentHealth == 0:

                print("Nice work, but don't get cocky now. You've got two more opponents ahead of you.")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Your next opponent is Goliath the Greatest. He really knows how to put up a fight. Don't let him beat you!")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("The battle will begin in")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("5")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("4")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("3")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("2")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("1")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Fight!")

            userInput = input()

            if userInput == "attack":
                userDamage = random.randint(0, 75)
                opponentDamage = random.randint(0, 50)
                opponentTwo = "Goliath the Greatest"
                opponentHealth -= userDamage

                if opponentHealth <= 0:
                    opponentHealth = 0

                if (userDamage < 25) and (userDamage > 0):
                        quoteOptions = [("You roundhouse kick {} in the abdomen and he begins to vomit.".format(
                            opponentTwo)), ("You punch {} in the stomach and he begins to tear up.".format(opponentTwo))]

                        print(random.choice(quoteOptions))
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print("You did {} damage to him".format(userDamage))
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print("He has {} health remaining.".format(opponentHealth))
                        print("---------------------------------------------------")


                elif (userDamage < 100) and (userDamage > 25):
                    quoteOptions = [("You drive your foot into {}'s groin with as much force as possible. You hear a high-pitched scream emit from his vocal chords.".format(
                            opponentTwo)), ("{} is intimidated by you and decides to slap himself mindlessly, in hopes that he will lose faster.".format(
                            opponentTwo))]
                    print(random.choice(quoteOptions))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("You did {} damage to him; a CRITICAL HIT!".format(userDamage))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("He has {} health remaining.".format(opponentHealth))
                    print("---------------------------------------------------")


                elif userDamage == 100:
                    print("{} forfeits... Coward.".format(opponentTwo))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("You did {} damage to him. INSTANT K.O".format(userDamage))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("He has {} health remaining.".format(opponentHealth))
                    print("---------------------------------------------------")

                else:
                    quoteOptions = [("Swing and a miss. You missed {}.".format(opponentTwo)), ("You underestimated {}".format(
                        opponentTwo))]
                    print(random.choice(quoteOptions))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("You did {} damage to him.".format(userDamage))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("He has {} health remaining.".format(opponentHealth))
                    print("---------------------------------------------------")


                # Opponent Attack
                if opponentHealth - 1 < opponentHealth:
                    userHealth = userHealth - opponentDamage
                    time.sleep(2)
                    print("Larry gathers the courage to punch you. Meh." or "Larry throws his shoe at you and starts to yell frantically while running away from you... You catch up soon enough, without breaking much of a sweat.")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("He did {} damage to you." .format(opponentDamage))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print("You have {} health remaining." .format(userHealth))
                    print("---------------------------------------------------")

                if userHealth == 0:
                    print("You lose!")
                    print("Come back do the Dojo when you become stronger. You are welcome back anytime, grasshopper.")
                    quit()
                elif opponentHealth == 0:
                    print("You win!")
                    break





            else:
                print("Type 'attack' to attack.")





# Invalid response
    else:
        print("Enter a valid response, young grasshopper.")
        if userInput == "start" is True:
            continue
```

I know this is terrible code, but it's my first one. Everything works atleast, up to the point where it says "You Win". It should continue onto the next fight, but instead it just stops there. Where is my main issue (besides poor formatting and redundant code)?

Comment: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html

Comment: I second @KarolyHorvath, try to break down your logic into smaller parts and put those parts into functions. Furthermore, add [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) to the code, so that you always know, where you are. It is simpler and faster to debugging it.

Comment: If you change the order:while True: userInput = input() for this userInput = input() while true ¿?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your code is waiting for user input again. Try giving `input` a prompt so you know which line has been hit.

eg.

```
result = input("type 'start' to start")
result = input("enter a move")
```